How can i get a quantity distribution by hour from a counter metric in Grafana?
For example, I have a http_server_requests_seconds_count{} counter metric.
I have some issues with writing a query in PromQL to get a quantity distribution by hour in Grafana. What operators i should use?
I would like to have something like this:
Desired dashboard in Grafana
Can anybody help? Any help would be appreciate

Does this answer your question? Grafana / PromQL query to chart a value per hour in a bar chart

Use increase(http_server_requests_seconds_count[1h]) and Min step of 1h

@markalex, thanks for your reply! The only thing i can't figure out how to transform it to have desired visualization in Grafana (where every bar is an hour).

In time series panel Graph style: bars.

@markalex, maybe my attached picture is not clear enough(
I would like like to have not a time series visualization, but something like bar gauge. But i can't use by default, because i must provide every hour (00, 01, 02, ..., 23) as a label.

Use time series panel, and configuration as I've said, and you'll get per hour bars

@markalex, i've tried to create a dashboard according to your instructions and got this: dashborad. Did i everything right? Are you expecting this result?

No. You didn't specify Min step for query. It is done in Query options (seen in your screenshot on top of the query)

@markalex, i don't have such option in "Query options", so i set min step below the qeury dashboard settings
